# Fluent nhibernate HasMany Mapping

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have 4 classes:

```
class Group
{
   int64 id;
   String name;
   GroupMembershipCollection members ;
}

class User
{
 int64 id;
 String name;
 GroupMembershipCollection groups;
}

class Role
{
 int64 id;
 String name;
}

class GroupMembership
{
  User User;
  Group Group;
 Role Role;
}

class GroupMembershipCollection : ObjectCollection<GroupMembership>
{}
```

My Mappings are as follows:

```
UserMap
{
    //other maps 
  this.HasMany<GroupMembershipCollection, GroupMembership>(p => p.Groups, cfg => cfg.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan());    }

GroupMap
{
    //other maps
   HasMany<GroupMembershipCollection, GroupMembership>(g => g.Members, cfg => cfg.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan());
}

GroupMemberShipMap
{
     References(x => x.User).Cascade.None();
 References(x => x.Group).Cascade.None();
 References(x => x.Role).Cascade.None();
 }
```

When I try adding Members to a Group it gives me the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_GroupMemberships_UserID".   on table dbo.Users

and when I try adding Groups to Member I get this:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_GroupMemberships_GroupID".
>       on table dbo.Groups

Please Help...

Comment: How are you adding members to a group? Are you assigning `GroupMembership.UserID`?

Comment: that is correct ..Also my Groupmembership table has correct entries for groupId , UserId and RoleId. it also throws this error NHibernate.AssertionFailurenull id in GroupMemberships

Comment: Have you tried using `.Inverse` on your `HasMany` mapping?

Comment: yes I have. But makes no difference